# If youtube works on DASH then why not it stores different quality of video in different URLs?

Tags: streaming, video

So I was going through a book on Computer Networks by James Kurose and Keith Ross on page 627 line 16 under the topic HTTP streaming and DASH the authors have mentioned that

> With DASH each video version is stored in the HTTP server, each with
>   a different URL.

However on youtube for each version of the video we find the same URL. Can someone explain me what the authors really mean or is it something different.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSi layer-4 are off-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin Can I ask why did you guyz decided so. I mean The name is network engineering means all type of question related to networking can be asked here. It does'nt make sense as to accept only some parts of OSI layer. I mean all the 7 parts are related to computer networking then why so specific. Ok One day I will be the moderator of this site and will vote for the acceptance of all layers in the Open Systems Interconnection model.

Comment: "_The name is network engineering means all type of question related to networking can be asked here._" No, it doesn't. Every SE site has a [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, and ours, under the **Off-Topic** section, says "_protocols above L4 in the OSI model (e.g. HTTP, FTP, etc)_."

Comment: The community decides what is on or off topic here. In fact, there is currently a debate on [meta] to see if we want to change what is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably reading an obsolete edition of the book.   Newer editions have different text. As the name implies, DASH allows the client to dynamically select a different data rate.

Comment: Thats the sixth edition 2017 version I have which I think is the latest version

Comment: DASH is a part of HTTP, and so is sadly off-topic here.  You can try asking about it on [sf] or [su].

Comment: But HTTP is related to networking too. Please don't close my question.

Comment: The community decided that protocols above the transport layer are off-topic here.  The other sites I mentioned are a better fit for this question.

Comment: Networking is a really broad term. Keep in mind that this site is about network *engineering*, not about networking in a general sense. As explain by Ron, HTTP, like many other thins related to network is off-topic here.